# How to find "doorskin"?

Tags: doors, plywood, lumber, veneer

Regarding this question: [What exactly is doorskin?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14884/what-exactly-is-doorskin)

Mine is not a duplicate because the one above does not fully answer my question, *exactly how can I find this product or something similar?*

I'm trying to make templates for countertops and all online references mention using strips of doorskin.  They even go so far to say that it can be found at any hardware store or home center.  I live near Chicago and cannot locate anything called "doorskin" at Ace, Home Depot, Lowes, or Menards.  They also do not sell any plywood thinner than ¼".  Nor ⅛" luan, nor single-ply plywood, or anything else like that.  [One answer mentions Lowes](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/55674/4425), but I cannot find anything called "doorskin" at Lowes online or in their stores.

I found 5 mm thick hardboard in 4x8 sheets at Home Depot, but that is far too hard/dense and way too thick.  The whole point of doorskin for countertop templates is that it's cheap and thin; cheap enough to throw away when done and thin enough to cut with heavy scissors or utility knife.

If the experts are correct and this product can be obtained from a chain home center, then why is this not listed online as a SKU on any of their websites?

I'm looking for help with how I can find "doorskin", or a suggestion for a reasonably priced substitute (*not cardboard since it would be too flimsy for accuracy*).

**EDIT**:  Not necessarily looking for shopping advice, but advice that will help me locate this product.

- What else might this be called?  So far, keywords such as "doorskin" or "⅛ luan" have yielded nothing productive.  (Google search results for "doorskin" are cluttered with car doors!)  Does a brand name come to mind for this?
- What kind of material could be used in place of this to make a suitable counter-top template?

**EDIT:**

[This will do.  Cheap and in stock locally at Menards.](https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/panel-products/hardwood-panels/4-x-8-sanded-utility-plywood/1252006/p-1444441906578.htm)

¼" x 4' x 8' Sanded Utility Plywood
(Actual Size .185" x 48" x 95-7/8")
Menards® SKU: 1252006

[⅛" would have been even better, but it's special order](https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/panel-products/hardwood-panels/4-x-8-sanded-utility-plywood/1252003/p-1444441906218.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that you can't find 1/8" plywood (luan), but have you asked about Thermo-ply? It's a thick waxed cardboard, supposedly for sheathing (ha!) but suitable for your application.

Ramboard (somewhat thick cardboard, sold on the roll) would be suitable if you used entire sheets (as opposed to strips). The factory edge on this is handy for straight lines.

Also possible (but a pain to cut into strips) would be countertop laminate material... a good lumberyard would probably have some old/kicked around product for cheap. (But then, if you had a good lumberyard, you'd already have some 1/8 luan...)

Comment: Actually, I found ⅛" plywood at Menard's but it's a special order item.  None of the big-box home centers have anything thinner than ¼" or 5 mm.   Even my large locally owned lumberyard does not have anything as thin as ⅛".

Comment: Never heard about Thermo-ply before.  According to Lowes and Home Depot sites, the product is "no longer available".  Maybe no demand for that in the Chicago area?

Comment: Thermo-ply might be scarce in Chicagoland because codes or local preferences. We use it mostly as cheap floor protection -- never as sheathing.

Answer (score -1):

I searched lowes an found [Luan](https://www.lowes.com/pd/RevolutionPly-5mm-Poplar-Plywood-Application-as-4-X-8/50121135) in 4x8 sheets available at many Chicago stores.

[image: locations]

**Plus you can always have them order it**.

Comment: You're demonstrating the problem I'm posting about.  That's not ⅛", and it's not even luan... *"Poplar - Premium grade blemish free face and primed back"*.  Destroying premium panels for making templates is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: It’s 5 mm thick which equals .2 inches which is approximately 3/16 of an inch.  Use it for a template and repurpose it for other small projects beats driving to Kentucky to find  luan